# invalid_request from getToken in Javascript from Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code in a node.js server application

```
app.get('/AuthorizeGoogle.html',function(req,res) {
    var auth        = new googleapis.OAuth2Client(config.google_login.client_id, config.google_login.client_secret, config.google_login.redirect_uri);
    var queryData   = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
    var code        = encodeURIComponent(queryData.code);

    console.log('Authorization Request recieved ');;

    console.log('Retrieiving token');
    auth.getToken(code,function(err,tokens) {
        console.log('Retrievied token ');
        console.log(tokens);
        console.log('**** ERROR ****');
        console.log(err);

        console.log('Calling setCredentials');
        auth.setCredentials(tokens);
        console.log('*****FINISHED!!!!!');
    });

    res.send('Authorization recieved ' + queryData.code)
});
```

This is called when Google returns and the user has authorised access to their Google account.

I get a code. However when auth.getToken() I am getting invalid_request. I have done this successfully in C#, but I am now moving to more open source tools hence moving the project to Node.js

Thanks in advance

OK - I looked again at the page suggested and did some refactoring of my code and that worked. I think what may have been the problem was the Url used to get the token in the first place.

I was already initialising the oauth2Client

```
var OAuth2Client = googleapis.OAuth2Client;
var oauth2Client;
oauth2Client    = new OAuth2Client(config.google_login.client_id, config.google_login.client_secret, config.google_login.redirect_uri);
```

The required Client Id, secret and redirect Url have been defined in a configuration file

So first all I changed the way I was generating that url. First off I set the Url to Login to Google to GoogleLogin.html which executes the following when the server receives a request for this page.

```
app.get('/GoogleLogin.html',function(req,res) {
    var scopes = "";

    // retrieve google scopes
    scopes += config.google_login.scopes.baseFeeds + " "
    scopes += config.google_login.scopes.calendar + " "
    scopes += config.google_login.scopes.drive + " "
    scopes += config.google_login.scopes.driveMetadata + " "
    scopes += config.google_login.scopes.profile + " "
    scopes += config.google_login.scopes.email + " "
    scopes += config.google_login.scopes.tasks

    var url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: 'offline',
        scope: scopes
    });

    res.writeHead(302, {location: url});
    res.end();


});
```

This first building a string of the scopes then generating the Authorization Url before redirecting to the generated url

When Google redirects back to the site the following is executed

```
app.get('/AuthorizeGoogle.html',function(req,res) {
    // var auth = new googleapis.OAuth2Client(config.google_login.client_id,config.google_login.client_secret, config.google_login.redirect_uri);
    var queryData   = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
    var code        = queryData.code;

    console.log('Authorization Request recieved ');;

    console.log('Retrieving token');
    oauth2Client.getToken(code,function(err,tokens) {
        console.log('Retrieved token ');
        console.log(tokens);
        console.log('**** ERROR ****');
        console.log(err);

        console.log('Calling setCredentials');
        oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
        console.log('*****FINISHED!!!!!');
    });

    res.send('Authorization recieved ' + queryData.code)
});
```

And this is now returning the Token and Refresh token correctly. Since it is the same code the only thing I can was wrong was the original call to Google.

Comment: You should not be calling `encodeURIComponent`.

Comment: Thanks, but I added that to see if it needs it - I still get invalid_request without it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: invalid\_request getToken](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33874339/error-invalid-request-gettoken)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to research what is done in the following github example: https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/examples/oauth2.js

Comment: That's what I based my code on. That code uses an input to give the code, if I've understood it properly. Of course in my instance the code is being sent directly from Google to the AuthorizeGoogle page - There is something I am missing but cannot see what.