# Error: invalid_request getToken

Tags: node.js, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

### Steps I have taken

**Using Google's developper console:**

1. I have created a project and created a client for that project.
2. I have activated Youtube API Data
3. I set a the callback to http://localhost:3000/callback
4. I have downloaded the "client_secrets".

**Node server initial steps:**

5. Using "client_secrets" I have created a new OAuth2Client instance that I named oauth2Client
6. I generated the URL with oauth2Client variable specifying the following:

---

```
var url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
            access_type: 'offline', //returns fresh token,
            scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner'
        });
```

---

**Google Authorization page:**

1. I go to the Generated URL and click authorize and get redirected to my callback on http://localhost:3000/callback

**Node Server final steps:**

1. I get the "code" in the URL (looks something like this: **4/gZpLEwZWD6OVEE7F5uXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX** )
2. Using the same oauth2Client variable I attempt to get the token like so:

---

```
oauth2Client.getToken(code, function (err, tokens) {
    // set tokens to the client
    console.log('errors ' + err);
    console.log('tokens ' + tokens);
    oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
})
```

---

The result from the console.log's are:

```
 errors Error: invalid_request
 tokens null
```

### Question

What is causing the `invalid_request`? What part did I miss?

---

Some other similar questions propose different solutions

*There seem to be quite a few questions on this subject, but most are specific questions with too often very vague answers.
I'm asking a generic question and looking for a specific answer.*

Comment: You didn't mention constructing of oauth2Client instance, so it can be a problem from lib issue on GutHub https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/231

Comment: I created the instance, but yes I forgot to mention it.

Comment: So did it help you (replacing array with string) ?

Comment: Yes thank you! that was it. go ahead and add it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't mention constructing of oauth2Client instance, so it can be a problem from lib issue on GutHub [google-api-nodejs-client/issues/231](http://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/231)

Namely, the third argument in constructor OAuth2 is going be a string

```
client_secrets.web.redirect_uris[0]
```

---

```
var oauth2Client = new OAuth2Client(
 client_secrets.web.client_id, 
 client_secrets.web.client_secret, 
 client_secrets.web.redirect_uris[0] //<-- take first uri
);
```

Comment: This solved the issue for me. When you download the credentials as JSON from the Google console, that value is set to an array while the OAuth2Client requires a string